# How to send multiple Socket IO socket.handshake.query values from Javascript client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

At server side I have two variables defined for *socket.handshake.query* as below. But I am not sure how to pass values to these two from client side (Javascript). 
Able to pass one value but not both. Can some one help me on this?

Server Side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
var userId = socket.handshake.query['userId'];
var shopId = socket.handshake.query['shopId'];
---
---}
```

Client Side:

```
socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:3000/", {     
    query: `userId=${userId.value}`,    
    // `shopId=${shopId.value}` // shopId also needs to be added to query           
});
```

Comment: Query should be an object so you can use: `query: { userId: userId.value, shopId: shopId.value }`

Comment: Thanks for your response Molda. It worked!!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Socket.IO Client Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-query-parameters), query should be an object. So You could do:

```
socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:3000/", {     
    query: {
       userId: userId.value,
       shopId: shopId.value
    }              
});
```